# Convert master dataframe into child dataframe with specific columns using substring

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to split master into child dataframe while splitting master dataframe i'm getting only one column that is masterDF whereas i'm trying to split into multiple columns.

```
ChildDF=
K0059122016022YU165754000000  000100000 L0000026009011    00020000           00007020149600001050000000N                         
K0059122016022YU100000000000  000200000 90800035433174    00010000           00009390150200001410000000N                         
K0059122016022YU160000000000  000100000 90800034921015    000100000000000000000014600000000000000000000N                         
K0059122016022YU165752000000  000100000 90800028370118    00020000           00011110000000000000000000N                         
K0059122016022YU100000000000  920161206083824VS122400000000000000000000000000000000000000020161206083824
K0059122016022YU165000000000  0001IVASQ S0000931025555    00020000           00004460000000000000000000N

listIs=List(Map(type->A,value1->1,value2->1),Map(type->B,value1->2,value2->6),Map(type->C,value1->8,value2->7),Map(type->D,value1->15,value2->2),Map(type->E,value1->17,value2->8),Map(type->F,value1->25,value2->8))


listIs.foreach(iteam => 
ChildDF.withColumn(iteam("type"),substring(ChildDF("masterDF"),iteam("value1").asInstanceOf[Int],iteam("value2").asInstanceOf[Int]))
)
ChildDF.createOrReplaceTempView("ChildTable")
val queryDF = "SELECT * from ChildTable"
sparkSession.sql(queryDF).cache().toDF().show()
```

output

```
masterDF
K0059122016022YU165754....
K0059122016022YU100000....
K0059122016022YU160000....
K0059122016022YU165752....
K0059122016022YU100000....
K0059122016022YU165000....
```

expected output(XXXXXX is splitted value)

```
    masterDF                   A          B        C
K0059122016022YU165754....   XXXXXX     XXXXXX  XXXXXX
K0059122016022YU100000....   XXXXXX     XXXXXX  XXXXXX
K0059122016022YU160000....   XXXXXX     XXXXXX  XXXXXX
K0059122016022YU165752....   XXXXXX     XXXXXX  XXXXXX
K0059122016022YU100000....   XXXXXX     XXXXXX  XXXXXX
K0059122016022YU165000....   XXXXXX     XXXXXX  XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map instead of foreach. `withColumn` will produce new data frame.

```
val newChildDF = listIs.map(iteam =>  
ChildDF.withColumn(iteam("type"),substring(ChildDF("masterDF"),iteam("value1").asInstanceOf[Int],iteam("value2").asInstanceOf[Int]))
)

newChildDF.createOrReplaceTempView("ChildTable")

val queryDF = "SELECT * from ChildTable"

sparkSession.sql(queryDF).cache().toDF().show()
```

Comment: Siva thanks for response still i'm getting error  scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset